# C# UDP - possible to tell windows to drop packets after a certain amount of time?

Tags: c#, udp, ttl

I have a very high rate UDP application and I'm a bit curious about the specific underpinnings here.  I am using the c# async methods and on EndReceive, I'm putting the work on a new thread, then calling BeginReceive.

It is my understanding that even if I'm currently at the code between EndReceive and BeginReceive, windows is still accepting UDP packets on this port - and whenever I call BeginReceive again, the next one will get picked up off of the stack.

Assuming this is all true (and if not, please set me straight) - is it possible for me to specify a TTL on those packets?  I need to send a response to the sender, and the sender is configured to disregard responses after a few seconds.

Thanks

Comment: If I am not mistaken UDP requires both ends to verify they recieved it.  This is the underline mechanic of UDP.  If you want one end to "give up" your looking for TCP packets.  If the default .NET Framework is not offering a way to do this, its a good sign, its not a good idea.

Comment: @Ramhound, Yes you're right, UDP requires both ends and it doesn't guarantees the receipt of packets.

Comment: @Ramhound I do not have control over the protocol.. but what I'm saying is that if I don't get to the packet within x amount of time after receipt, I want to discard it.  I was hoping for a way to either have that take place automatically, or possibly get that data somehow.  AFAIK the OS will 'receive' the packet for me before I actually get it from EndReceive.

Answer (score 4):

When the Network Interface Card delivers a datagram off the wire, the operating system places it into the receive queue of your socket.  It waits there until you read it with the `recvfrom()` system call, or the high-level wrapper of your choice.

You can determine the size of this buffer by calling `getsockopt()` for `SO_RCVBUF`.  Default and maximum sizes vary *greatly* by operating system and version.

Network datagrams do not carry any timing information so there is no intrinsic way to expire them based on time.  How you choose to proceed really depends on exactly where you expect delays to come from.

- If you are concerned about the time from send to processing, then you must coordinate clocks between the sender and receiver, then have the sender place a time stamp in each datagram just before it is sent.  That's the only way you can know the actual time between events.  But bear in mind that network delay can vary greatly, so simply discarding all packets older than some amount could result in you discarding *all* packets.
- If your concern is only for the time between a packet is received and when it is processed (ignoring network latency), then you will need to have a separate thread read off the datagrams as fast as they arrive, note their times, and store them in an internal, thread-safe queue.  That's a lot of work, and will introduce significant overhead, so you may first want to examine why there is a delay in processing.
- If the packets are being sent at a fairly fixed rate and/or your concern is not so much with timing as with having backlog of unprocessed packets, then you may simply want to reduce the size of the receive queue (`setsockopt()` with `SO_RCVBUF`).  While the receive queue is full, any arriving datagrams will be silently discarded.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement to discard packets when they get too old is application-specific and (AFAIK) isn't something UDP can provide you with. Windows might be "automatically" receiving and buffering datagrams for you, but how it does that is an implementation detail of the network stack.

I'd divide this into two pieces:

1. Receive and enqueue messages as fast as they arrive.

   - Possibly start dropping the oldest messages even at this stage if you want to limit the size of your receive queue.
2. Dequeue messages:

   - Dropping them on the floor if they're too old.
   - Processing and acknowledging them otherwise.

Step 2 could probably be parallelised to try and ensure that your consumers keep up.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to specify TTL when sending but TTL is decremented by each router as it passes through and isn't time based.  This isn't the field you're looking for.

Thus, if a packet has  a TTL of three, it becomes 2 after the first router, 1 after the second router and 0 at the third router where the packet will be dropped without any notification to the sender.

Comment: "without any notification to the sender"?  What's [ICMP *TTL expired in transit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Time_exceeded) code good for then?